# Can powerset be reduced and transformed to knapsack?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, powerset

I am wondering can powerset problem be transformed and reduced to knapsack problem? It seems to me that they are identical that for example the changes making problem which we can think of it as powerset that every recursive stage I launch 2 recursive calls (one takes the `i`th element, and the other one bypass it). I can also solve it with dynamic programming just like knapsack problem, so this makes me wondering if all the powerset problem can be transformed to knapsack problem. Is that correct ?

The following are the code fragment of the coin changes making one with O(2<sup>N</sup>) time complexity and one with dynamic programming O(N<sup>2</sup>) runtime.

```
// O(2^N) time complexity
void bruteforce(int[] coins, int i, int N, String expr) 
{
     if (i == coins.length) {
         if (N == 0)
            count++;
         return;
     }

     if (N >= coins[i])
         recursion(coins, i, N - coins[i], expr + " " + coins[i]);
     recursion(coins, i + 1, N, expr);
}

// O(N^2) time complexity
int dynamicProgramming(int[] coins, int N) 
{
     int [] dp = new int[N + 1];
     dp[0] = 1;

     for(int i = 0; i < coins.length; i++)
         for(int j = coins[i]; j <= N; j++)
             dp[j] += dp[j - coins[i]];
     return dp[N];
}
```

Comment: They are basically the same. Also your `bruteforce` method can be converted to a dynamic approach by using memoization.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 that's correct. So does that mean powerset in general have a O(N^2) solution ?

Comment: What do yo exactly mean by powerset problem?

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 if you have 3 items, then the powerset would be {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2},{1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}, and empty set

Comment: Ok, you claim you can print the powerset with dynamic approach in linear time. Try to solve your *powerset* problem with 50 items and see how much time it takes.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 well as you just said (and later deleted) that some subset of powerset can be solved by dynamic programming, right? as you don't need all 2^n subsets. In the example I showed which is the coin changes making problem that is a subset of powerset, correct ?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment because I spotted something wrong in it and I couldn't edited it. Basically if you want to count some specific subsets that follow some rules like their sum is less than *k* you can do it with dp because you don't need to generate all those subsets and only need to count them but then the problem won't be powerset it is called subset sum or knapsack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finding powerset (generating all subsets of a set) can't be done in a way that has a complexity better than O(2<sup>n</sup>) because there are 2<sup>n</sup> subsets and merely printing them will take exponential time.
Problems like subset sum, knapsack or coin change are related to powerset because you *implicity* have to generate all subsets but there is a big difference between them and powerset. In these problems you are only counting some subsets and you aren't required to *explicity* generate those subsets. For example if the problem asks you to find all the ways to change X dollars to some coins then you can't solve this in linear time because you have to generate all the desired subsets and there could be 2<sup>n</sup> of them.